# Is anyone using Velocity for NHibernate second level caching in production

Tags: nhibernate, appfabric

Is anyone using Microsoft Velocity for NHibernate second level caching? What are your experiences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no go-live licence for Velocity yet (as at CTP3), in fact the licence specifically prohibits installing it on live servers even for testing. Plus I wouldn't ever go into production with a CTP version of a product, I'd always wait for it to RTM first (and I assume other people have the same kind of opinion). So on that basis it seems extremely unlikely that anyone is using it in production with or without NHibernate.